# Guava: How to create an explicit Ordering from a List and a single element?

Tags: java, guava, comparator

In Guava, given a `Collection<E>` and an element `e` of type `E` that I know is in the collection, I'd like to create a custom [`Ordering<E>`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) that sorts `e` first and then the rest of the collection. However, the way to get there seems awfully complicated:

```
Collection<String> values = ImmutableList.of("apples", "oranges", "pears");
String first = "oranges";

List<String> remainingValues = newArrayList(values);  // this
remainingValues.remove(first);                        // seems
Ordering<String> myOrdering =                         // very
    Ordering.explicit(first, remainingValues.toArray( // complicated!
        new String[remainingValues.size()]));         // is there an easier way?
```

What I'm wishing for is either something like this:

```
Ordering.explicit(first);
```

(I'd like this to sort `first` to the beginning and retain the order of all other elements, but the docs say the resulting Ordering will throw a `ClassCastException` for elements not explicitly listed.)

Or like this:

```
Ordering.explicit(first, values.toArray(/* etc */));
```

(But this would fail because `first` would be a duplicate value)

Can anybody come up with a concise way of doing what I want?

BTW, it doesn't have to be an `Ordering`, it could also be a workaround for creating an `Iterable` in the specified Order, but again, this is very complicated:

```
Iterable<String> sorted = Iterables.concat(
                             ImmutableList.of(first),
                             Iterables.filter(values, not(equalTo(first))));
```

Comment: On the linked javaDoc, the example under allEqual catches my eye, as well as the nullsFirst/Last methods. I wonder if you had a comparator of the value to extract being less than anything else, chained to a ordering that assumes all other values are equal ?

Comment: @Charlie yup, that would work, but it wouldn't actually be any less complicated than what I am doing

Comment: Tis true... But a generic itemFirst/itemLast might make a good patch to guava itself... if accepted then: `Ordering.allEqual().itemFirst("oranges")` would be extremely simple :-D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, here's one way to do it, but you may not find it much better.

```
final String special = "oranges";
Collections.sort(
    list,
    new Comparator<String>() {
      public int compare(String left, String right) {
        return ComparisonChain.start()
            .compareTrueFirst(left.equals(special), right.equals(special))
            .compare(left, right)
            .result();
      }
    });
```

[ComparisonChain docs](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html)

[Relevant Guava feature request](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/332) -- please add any details.

Comment: Sure, I am aware of that way, which (apart from ComparisonChain) is actually the traditional Java way of doing it. But: I like to use Guava because in most cases it actually makes life easier. This doesn't make anything easier, and I don't like the destructive  Collections.sort call.

Comment: Hmm, since none of the answers seems satisfactory, this one gets the checkmark for suggesting to file an issue. I may eventually do that.

Answer (score 2):

This is more convenient and less repetitive if you have more special values:

```
class PriorityComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {
    private final List<T> values;

    public PriorityComparator(T... values) {
        this.values = Arrays.asList(values);
    }

    @Override public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        int idx1 = values.indexOf(o1);
        int idx2 = values.indexOf(o2);
        if (idx1 > -1) {
            return idx2 > -1 ? idx1 - idx2 : -1;
        }
        return idx2 > -1 ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

You can use it in a comparison chain like

```
return ComparisonChain.start()
    .compare(left, right, new PriorityComparator<>("oranges", "apples"))
    .compare(left, right)
    .result();
```

It will sort the elements as specified in the `PriorityComparator`, other elements are reported as being equal.

It's also easy to require `T` to be comparable and use that as the default value instead:

```
class PriorityComparator2<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<T> {
    private final List<T> values;

    public PriorityComparator2(T... values) {
        this.values = Arrays.asList(values);
    }

    @Override public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        int idx1 = values.indexOf(o1);
        int idx2 = values.indexOf(o2);
        if (idx1 > -1) {
            return idx2 > -1 ? idx1 - idx2 : -1;
        }
        return idx2 > -1 ? 1 : o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this answer isn't easier/less complicated than what you already have but at least it can be re-used :)

```
class FirstOrdering<T extends Comparable> extends Ordering<T> {

    private T first;

    public FirstOrdering(T first) {
        this.first = first;
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(@Nullable T left, @Nullable T right) {
        // TODO Nullchecks...
        if (first.equals(left)) return -1;
        if (first.equals(right)) return 1;
        return left.compareTo(right);
    }
}

final String first = "B";
    new FirstOrdering(first).
            sortedCopy(Arrays.asList("A", "D", "E", first));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [NullsFirstOrdering](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/NullsFirstOrdering.java) as your template and create a ordering that sorts the first element, delegating to another ordering for everything else:

```
public class ItemFirstComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> implements Serializable {
  private final Comparator<? super T> comparator;
  private final Object item;

  ItemFirstComparator(Object item, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    this.item = item;
    comparator = checkNotNull(comparator);
  }

  @Override public int compare(@Nullable T left, @Nullable T right) {
    if (left == right) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (Objects.equals(left, item)) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (Objects.equals(right, item)) {
      return 1;
    }
    return comparator.compare(left, right);
  }
}
```

You then can chain orderings easily: `Ordering.from(new ItemFirstComparator("oranges", Ordering.allEqual()))`.

## Edit

Changed the code to use Comparator instead of Ordering, the rest stays the same.

Comment: Subclassing Ordering seems like a code smell. I'm surprised it's even possible.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd although it is possible so subclass ordering, I agree with you that it is smelly. I therefore changed my code sample to Comparable.

Comment: Subclassing is definitely overused, but Ordering, at least, is designed to be subclassed: "You can also skip the comparator step and extend Ordering directly." http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source for com.google.common.collect.ExplicitOrdering, it maintains a map holding the rank of each item, and `compare` simply compares the ranks.  You can do the same thing yourself, but forcing the designated first item's rank to -1, which is before all other items.

If you have a List (as the question's title states), Java 8 streams make building the map moderately convenient:

```
Map<T, Integer> rankMap = IntStream.range(0, list.size()).boxed().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(list::get, i -> list.get(i).equals(first) ? -1 : i));
Comparator<T> cmp = Comparator.comparing(rankMap::get);
```

If you have only a Collection (as the question's body states), you'll need to use a for loop to build the map:

```
Map<T, Integer> rankMap = new HashMap<>(coll.size());
int rank = 0;
for (T t : coll)
    rankMap.put(t, t.equals(first) ? -1 : rank++);
Comparator<T> cmp = Comparator.comparing(rankMap::get);
```

You can turn the Comparator into an Ordering with Ordering.from, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

If you were considering using explicit ordering to begin with, it kind of assumes your list did not have duplicates. At which point, `FluentIterable` and `.toSet()` can make this trivial. Duplicates will be simply ignored (as opposed to erroring out).

```
Iterable<String> sorted = FluentIterable.of(first).append(values).toSet();
    or
ImmutableList<String> sorted =
    FluentIterable.of(first).append(values).toSet().toList();
```

IMO, your first suggestion is actually not that bad, and also works if your list has duplicate values non-first. If you use a FluentIterable though, it looks better, as you can concat mixed Iterable and elements types:

```
Iterable<String> others = Iterables.filter(values, not(equalTo(first)));
Iterable<String> sorted = FluentIterable.of(first).append(others);
```

The catch here though is that if you have more than 1 "first" element, you'll lose the copies.

The fix is trivial though:

```
Iterable<String> firsts = Iterables.filter(values, equalTo(first)));
Iterable<String> others = Iterables.filter(values, not(equalTo(first));
Iterable<String> sorted = FluentIterable.from(firsts).append(others);
```

This requires iterating your collection twice, but the algorithm is trivial, and probably faster than anything Comparator based. If I had to code review such an implementation, I'd accept this without batting an eye, because it's super readable/maintainable, and I'd have 100% faith it works as intended.

If all else fails though, manual iteration never hurt anyone:

```
List<String> firsts = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> others = new ArrayList<>();
values.forEach(element -> (first.equal(element) ? firsts : others).add(element));
Iterable<String> sorted = FluentIterable.from(firsts).append(others);
```

Finally, note that since these use `FluentIterable`, getting a collection (`ImmutableList`) out of these is as trivial as appending `.toList()` to you `FluentIterable`.

Answer (score 0):

This also sounds like a "ranking" sort, where objects that "are first" have a higher weigh: So the 1-liner ordering would be:

```
Ordering.explicit(true, false).onResultOf(first::equals);
   or the more general
Ordering.natural().reverse().onResultOf(rankFunction);
```