# Object sorting using java comparator but with fixed value should be in last value in a sorted list

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparator

I have a MasterPayee object sorting based on Payee category code with alphabetical order now i need to get Other Services category code to be last in the sorted list

**List after sorting applied**

```
Financial and Insurance services

Government Sectors

Other Services

Telecommunications and Utilities

Transportation Services
```

**Required list as follows**

```
Financial and Insurance services
Government Sectors
Telecommunications and Utilities
Transportation Services
Other Services
```

Need to acheive Other Services as last in the list Following Comparator is using to sort the list

```
Collections.sort(masterPayees, getCategoryNameComparatorByMasterPayee());

private Comparator<MasterPayee> getCategoryNameComparatorByMasterPayee() {
    Comparator<MasterPayee> categoryNameComparatorByMasterPayee = new Comparator<MasterPayee>() {
        public int compare(MasterPayee o1, MasterPayee o2) {
            return (((MasterPayee) o1).getPayee_category().toString()
                    .compareToIgnoreCase(((MasterPayee) o2).getPayee_category().toString()));
        }

    };
    return categoryNameComparatorByMasterPayee;
}
```

**Other Services** should be always last in the sorted list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ordering with partial explicit and then another order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125743/ordering-with-partial-explicit-and-then-another-order)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Comparator<MasterPayee> categoryNameComparatorByMasterPayee = new Comparator<MasterPayee>(){
    public int compare(MasterPayee o1, MasterPayee o2) {
        if (((MasterPayee) o1).getPayee_category().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Other Services") && ((MasterPayee) o1).getPayee_category().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(((MasterPayee) o2).getPayee_category().toString())) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (((MasterPayee) o1).getPayee_category().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Other Services")) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (((MasterPayee) o2).getPayee_category().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Other Services")) {
            return -1;
        }
        else return (((MasterPayee) o1).getPayee_category().toString().compareToIgnoreCase(((MasterPayee) o2).getPayee_category().toString()));
    }
};
```

It treats an object with "Other Services" always as "larger", thus making it appear at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use guava'a Ordering if you know all values that may be sorted.

To create comparator you can speccify your values like this:

```
Ordering<String> ordering1 =  Ordering.explicit("Financial and Insurance services","Government Sectors","Telecommunications and Utilities","Transportation Services","Other Services");
```

You may also provide List with your values as argument to `Ordering.explicit()`.

Comment: You should probably add a little detail to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a constant map <Payee, Integer> and in the comparator use the value.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can handle the logic gracefully by using a ternary expression.

```
private Comparator<MasterPayee> getCategoryNameComparatorByMasterPayee() {
    Comparator<MasterPayee> categoryNameComparatorByMasterPayee = new Comparator<MasterPayee>() {
        public int compare(MasterPayee o1, MasterPayee o2) {
            String s1 = ((MasterPayee) o1).getPayee_category().toString();
            String s2 = ((MasterPayee) o1).getPayee_category().toString();
            boolean b1 = s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Other Services");
            boolean b2 = s2.equalsIgnoreCase("Other Services");

            return b1 ? (b2 ? 0 : 1) : (b2 ? -1 : s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2));
        }
    };
    return categoryNameComparatorByMasterPayee;
}
```

This avoids having code which is difficult to read, and therefore difficult to maintain.  And if we need to change the logic here, we might only have to make minimal changes.

Comment: Here b1 and b2 will return a int and it throws compile time error

Comment: @Kiran Sorry, I had intended to use `String#equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only a limited set of those elements I would write them as `enum`.

A `name` for the output text and an `ordinal` for the sorting. It's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion, if "Other Services" is always present, remove it from the list, do the sorting, and then add "Other Services" last. That way you can keep the sorting logic simple and add the exception separately.

If not always present, then you can look for it first, and then only add if it was present.

Answer (score 0):

If the list of strings is fixed ordering is based on business logic instead of string value, then i recommend using EnumMap collections.

```
enum Industry{
    FINANCE, GOVERNMENT, UTILITIES, TRANSPORT, OTHER
}

public class StreamEnumMap {
    public static void main(String... strings){
        Map<Industry, String> industryMap = new EnumMap<>(Industry.class);
        industryMap.put(Industry.FINANCE, "Financial and Insurance services");
        industryMap.put(Industry.GOVERNMENT,"Government Sectors");
        industryMap.put(Industry.UTILITIES,"Telecommunications and Utilities");
        industryMap.put(Industry.OTHER,"Other Services");
        industryMap.put(Industry.TRANSPORT, "Transportation Services");

        industryMap.values().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

This produces the results in the below order,

```
Financial and Insurance services
Government Sectors
Telecommunications and Utilities
Transportation Services
Other Services
```

Comment: Idea is good but I will retrieve these values from DB.So I am not sure how many added in future

Comment: @kiran If it is possible to add an priority column in the DB then you can use both these columns for sorting. Personally i would prefer numeric sorting compared to String sorting. Further using priority column will move sorting logic to the DB. This way if in future you have to change the order then it will be easier