# Sort object List by another List using Java Comparators

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, comparator

Thare are two input lists as follows:

```
inputA = [
            {
               name: "A",
               age: 20
            }, 
            {
               name: "B",
               age: 30
            },
            {  name: "C",
               age: 25
            },
            {  name: "D",
               age: 28
            }
          ]

inputB = ["D", "B"]
```

My preferred output list must be as follows:

```
expectedOutput = [
            {
               name: "D",
               age: 28
            }, 
            {
               name: "B",
               age: 30
            },
            {  name: "A",
               age: 20
            },
            {  name: "C",
               age: 25
            }
          ]
```

What I have done so far looks like below:

```
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
Collections.sort(inputA, Comparator
    .comparing(a -> 
    if (inputB.indexOf(a.getName()) > -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return count.incrementAndGet();
    })
    .thenComparingInt(a -> a.getAge()));
```

The output I am getting is as follows

```
actualOutput = [
            {
               name: "D",
               age: 28
            }, 
            {
               name: "B",
               age: 30
            },
            {  name: "C",
               age: 25
            },
            {  name: "A",
               age: 20
            }
          ]
```

Problem is with the elements that doesn't have their name in the list `inputB`. There order doesn't have the original order in `inputA`. For the original order to persist `{ name: "A", age: 20 }` should come before `{ name: "C", age: 25 }`

How can i solve this issue while using the comparator chaining strategy?

**UPDATE**
Sorting logic is, if inputA has objects where the names are equal to the inputB list, those elements should come to the top of the inputA and then those elements must be sorted by their age while keeping the original order of the other elements in inputA which are not present in inputB

This is not a possible duplicate, because this question tries to compare two lists and also sort the common elements by a property of an object from the the first list while leaving the rest of the elements in their original order.

Comment: Should that be `.thenComparingInt` instead of just `comparingInt`?

Comment: I am curious to know what's the reasoning behind the processing with ```return count.incrementAndGet();``` in the else case. That where the issue lies

Comment: What even is the rule by which you want to order your items?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ordering with partial explicit and then another order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125743/ordering-with-partial-explicit-and-then-another-order)

Comment: @Joe How can this be a duplicate of the problem you are stating? Just read the question properly and also compare the two accepted answers of this and the question you are referring

Comment: @simplelenz with the updated explanation of the sorting logic in your update, I can see more clearly what you're trying to achieve. You *could* solve it by composing Guava `Ordering`s, but I agree this is not a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see it, you need to sort elements by age if the name is contained in the `inputB` list and leave the rest of the elements as they are if they aren't contained in the `inputB` list. The elements sorted by age should appear at the top of the result, while the unsorted ones should appear at the bottom.

If this is what you need to do, you can use `Comparator.comparingInt` and let it return an integer that is either the age (for the first case) or `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (for the other case).

You should optimize the check over `inputB`, so that it is fast. For this, you could create a `HashSet` from `inputB`.

This is the code:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(inputB);

Collections.sort(inputA, Comparator.comparingInt(a -> set.contains(a.getName()) ? 
                                                      a.getAge() : 
                                                      Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

This works, as long as you don't have an age that is equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

The idea is that you always compare by age, but if an element doesn't belong to `inputB`, you turn the age into `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. This will have two effects: first, it will make elements not contained in `inputB` appear at the bottom; second, as you always return `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, the order of the `inputA` list is preserved, because `Collections.sort` implements a *stable sort*.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code is that the second comparator gets activated on all items in `inputA`. This means, even the items that are not in `inputB` will get sorted breaking the original order of `inputA`. You can avoid it like this:

```
Collections.sort(inputA, Comparator.comparing(a ->
{
    if (inputB.indexOf(a.getName()) > -1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
})
.thenComparingInt(a -> 
{
   if (inputB.indexOf(a.getName()) > -1)
   {
       return a.getAge();
   }
   return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}));
```

However, I'm not sure if it's desirable to call `IndexOf()` twice specially if `inputB` is unsorted. May be worth looking at the bytecode generated to see if that gets optimized.

One thing is that, using a count doesn't have any impact on the comparison. You just need to return -1, 0, or 1 in a comparison operation. So, there's no value in doing a thread-safe increment on a count.

On the other hand, if you can, introduce a `priority` field in the class that defines the object in `inputA`. Then you can get around the issue of calling `indexOf()` multiple times like:

```
Collections.sort(inputA, Comparator.comparing(a ->
{
   if (inputB.indexOf(a.getName()) > -1)
   {
       a.setPriority(a.getAge());
       return 0;
   }

   a.setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
   return 1;
})
.thenComparingInt(a -> a.getPriority()));
```